# Is it possible to "hook" classes to running .net programs?

Tags: c#, .net, hook

I was playing with dll injection lately (mostly with [easyhook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)), and I started wondering - is it possible to do something similar with .net classes?

For example, to override TcpStream and SslStream to monitor application's communications. The hoop app would inject itself into another app and show logs of traffic sent and received.

I know that there are easier ways to do monitor application's traffic, but this still would be a really nice tool to have.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible. If you can inject a DLL into an application, you can [self host the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x0wh2z3.aspx) in that application. [This website](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-to-inject-a-managed-assembly-dll/) provides a detailed tutorial on it if you can tolerate the giant photos.

However, what you are detailing is a little more complicated than just DLL injection; it's a different question really. You would need to defeat the strong naming of assemblies in .NET, replace the respective .NET assemblies on your machines and then write your new SslStream classes to report back to you. This would require a lot of work though, because you need to re-build each assembly for each class you plan on tinkering with, from the ground up.

The alternative would be to hook into the underlying socket provider that .NET is going to use anyway. You can intercept winsock communications with easyhook and then to decrypt the SSL stream you will need to analyze the memory of the target application to extract the cipher and keying information.

Comment: Changing core .net assemblies like system etc is impossible or atleast very very difficult. You can try it yourself.

Comment: @ArsenZahray It is difficult but not impossible. I've done it before and it is a matter of exploiting a vulnerability in the way .NET verifies assembly strong names. It's published online and with a bit of searching you can find it. It isn't something I can detail in a comment easily. But as an FYI, changing mscorlib is actually easy, there's an option in Visual Studio to not even include it in your own code, but you have to implement your own. Copy and paste the new assembly and it works as long as you strong name it and trust that on your system.

Comment: can you link to a way to change System.dll? I've tried doing something with reflector, but it just won't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could also detour the strong name verification to return true regardless of the assembly being modified; I've seen it done in both C++ and C# before.

Comment: it's not about strong name verification. the assembly is probably written in c++ or something (with non-managed code as well) and Reflector simply can't cope with that. But it's really interesting that strong name verification can be suspended!